# azure automate stored procedure

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have a simple stored procedure which returns nothing, it just does some data moving. I need it to  run every night or whatever. 
Is this possible from Azure.

I've tried for 2 days to do it with 'Logic Apps', and although i can get the 'Microsoft SQL Connector' to  run every minute without error using the 'Recurrence' trigger, it does not touch the database. e.g. The SP does not get called.
So i'm not sure what its doing.

Now every time I Delete all 'Logic apps' and start again, the 'new' 'Microsoft SQL Connector'  always has the OLD SP name already entered in the 'Choose an action' section and I cant remove it in order to  get to  the screen where you choose tables, poll results etc.

So looking for way to  automate simple SP call on Azure.

Comment: try ssis for data movement

Comment: Thought I could do all this simple stuff without needing a VM.
Thought that was the point of Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure App Service also includes Webjobs allowing you to run programs and scripts on demand, continuously, or on a schedule.  Take a look at this documentation page to get you started: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

Comment: Thanks. 
Used to  be 30 second, 4 click job. 
Now its, learn a new SDK, build projects, try to follow examples that have nothing to  do  with what I'm trying to do and take 4 weeks out for research. 
All to run a SP at 12am from azure whose sole purpose was to  make this exact task easier. lol

Anyway not your problem. 
Cheers again.

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger  :-)